# Initializing object in __init__ parameter list for default value returning same instance

Tags: python

Given the sample code below:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        return

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, foo = Foo()):
        print(foo)

bar1 = Bar()
bar2 = Bar()

print(bar1)
print(bar2)
```

Outputs the following:

```
<__main__.Foo object at 0x000002A989A2E9B0>
<__main__.Foo object at 0x000002A989A2E9B0>
<__main__.Bar object at 0x000002A989A2EA20>
<__main__.Bar object at 0x000002A989A2EA90>
```

It was unexpected that both instances of `Foo` were identical.  I was hoping that each subsequent creation of a `Bar()` object would have it's own unique version of a `Foo` object.

How can I modify my example so that each call to `Bar()` will create its own unique version of `Foo`?  Do I need to use `__new__` somehow?

Comment: It shouldn't be unexpected. Default arguments are evaluated when the function is defined, not when it is called. If the instance of `Foo` is immutable, it won't matter if it's the same instance for each call. Otherwise, it does matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Foo:
    pass

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, foo = None):
        if foo is None:
            foo = Foo()
        print(foo)

bar1 = Bar()
bar2 = Bar()

print(bar1)
print(bar2)
```

or

```
import attr

class Foo:
    pass

@attr.s
class Bar(object):
    foo = attr.ib(default=attr.Factory(Foo))

bar1 = Bar()
bar2 = Bar()

print(bar1.foo)
print(bar2.foo)
```